# Are there only 2 types of motion -- Translational & Rotational?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, kinematics

When searching up the different types of motion, results show circular motion, translational motion, oscillatory motion, rotational motion, periodic motion, etc. But just to clear things up in my head, all types of motion can be described as either translational or rotational right? To me it seems like an object either moves its position or moves its orientation(rotation), and things like circular motion and oscillatory motion are just used to describe specific patterns of translational motion. Thanks.

Comment: What about spiralling, zigzagging and oscillatory motion?

Comment: All of the motions you describe are either linear, non-linear, or a combination of the two.

Comment: Spiralling motion is just an object changing it's position in a spiral pattern, oscillatory motion is an object changing its position in a back and forth pattern, zigzagging is an object changing its position in a zigzag pattern. All of these involve an object moving it's position in space, so they are all translational motion in a specific pattern that have formulas to describe their patterns of movement. That leaves only an object not moving it's position, but changing its orientation, which would be rotational motion. Cannot all motion be either a change in position or orientation? @my2cts

Comment: Are you asking only about rigid objects? Real objects can elongate and contract in various directions, which is neither translation nor rotation.

Comment: @Chemomechanics I'm taking AP Physics 1, so I believe we just deal with regular rigid bodies

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is only **one** kind of 3D motion at any instant. This is the so called [Chasles' theorem](https://phys.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Classical_Mechanics/Classical_Mechanics_(Dourmashkin)/20%3A_Rigid_Body_Kinematics_About_a_Fixed_Axis/20.06%3A_Appendix_20A_Chasless_Theorem-_Rotation_and_Translation_of_a_Rigid_Body).

This motion is that of a rotation about some arbitrary axis, *and* a parallel translation along the axis. This motion is often called the screw motion, and it is the basis for [Screw Theory](https://publish.illinois.edu/ece470-intro-robotics/files/2023/02/07-lecture-slides.pdf) in the study of rigid body motions, kinematics, and robotics.

Any instantaneous motion of a rigid body can be decomposed into a screw motion defined by the rotation axis direction, a point somewhere along the axis of rotation, the magnitude (speed) of the rotation and the pitch which represents the ratio of translation to rotation.

The general screw motion has two special cases

- Pure rotation is when the pitch is zero and there is no translation
- Pure translation has its axis of rotation at infinity and zero pitch, or just a translational velocity (zero rotation) which means the pitch is infinite. Both interpretations are equally valid.

When looking at 2D motion, then the axis of rotation *must* be out of plane if it exists. You might have heard of the term for ["centre of rotation"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instant_centre_of_rotation). This designates the point where the rotation axis intersects the plane of motion.

Comment: So the motion of an object can be described in terms of change in rotation and position as one collective motion, and the various types of motion I mentioned in the question are just specific ways/patterns of motion? Also, your answer as well as another comment mention rigid bodies. How does the definition of motion change when dealing with non rigid bodies?

Comment: @RandoStudent - yes. Rigid bodies are collections of particles that maintain fixed distances from each other. Non-rigid bodies are described in terms of collections of particles and may or may not move together, which means there is no notion of rotational velocity anymore.

Answer (score 0):

By "motion" I think you mean all the continuous changes (transformations) one body can do to another body in space-time.  There are more than just translations and rotations.  In fact, it is a fundamental physics experiment to discover what they are, and then to mathematically explain them.

Suppose I have a small cube of material in my hand.  What can I do with my fingers to the cube by a continuous amount?  I can:

1. Rotate the cube about any of 3-axis by any continuous number of degrees.
2. Stretch/compress the cube perpendicular to any of the 3 faces by a continuous fraction of its present size.
3. Parallel-piped any of the 3 faces of the cube by an amount measured by the continuous degrees of angle that the edges of the face have moved inward or outward from their old positions.
4. Translate the cube in any of 3 directions by a continuous number of meters.
5. Wait for the cube by a continuous number of seconds.
6. Give the cube a velocity in any of 3 directions by a continuous number of [meters/sec].

By fiddling with the cube, we tentatively (because we might have missed some transformation!) conclude that any other motions(=transformations) of the cube can be accomplished by doing some sequence of the transformations listed above.  Let G be the set of all these transformations, and $g$ is one of the transformations in G.  Then what are some of the properties of the elements $g$?

a) G is closed under the product $g_2g_1$. Doing $g_1$ and then $g_2$ always results in a $g_3$ that is in the set G.

b) Every element $g$ has an inverse $g^{-1}$ in G.  For example, for a rotation by 10 degrees about the x-axis there is an inverse transformations by -10 degrees about the x-axis.

c) There is an identity element I in G.  It is when you do nothing to the cube.

d) All the transformations $g$ are associative.  That means:  $g_1*(g_2*g_3)=(g_1*g_2)*g_3$.

A set of transformations that obey these four rules is called a mathematical group.  Because each element $g$ is labelled by a continuous parameter, G is a special type of group called a Lie Group.

Further study of transforming the cube with your fingers will reveal that often $g_1*g_2\ne g_2*g_1$.  Learning what the product $g_1*g_2$ gives for $g_3$ allows us to determine which mathematical Lie Group physics is.  Some of the subsets (subgroups) of G have been named and used to explain a lot of physics (eg: why particles have only integer and half-integer angular momenta, and why adding velocities always gives less than c):

Rotation Group O(3):  The transformations (1)

General Linear Group GL(3): The transformations (1), (2), (3)

Lorentz Group O(3,1): The transformations (1), (6)

Poincare Group: The transformations (1), (6), (4), (5)

(Speculation: GL(4): The transformations (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6)  )

There are other Lie Groups used for the gauge transformations and internal symmetries.  However, these do transformations in charge, isospin, or color space ...not the space-time accessible to our fingers used above.

Your seemingly simple question of which motions exist, touches on some of the most modern ideas (and puzzles) in physics.